# Is there a way to create a saved search to find the buildable quantity of assembly items that are back-ordered

Tags: search, netsuite

We need to establish what assembly items can be built to meet existing demand, i.e. the items on back order. The results should only list the assemblies + volume that can be built based on the component items being available.

Answer (score 0):

To show the **Buildable Quantity** of all **Assembly/Bill Of Materials** items that are currently on back-order:

Create a Item Saved Search as follows:

---

- **Criteria (Standard) Tab**

  - **Type** ANY OF **Assembly/Bill Of Materials**
  - **Inventory Location** ANY OF **- None -** and **<Your Location>**
  - **Member Item Fields > Inventory Location** ANY OF **- None -** and **<Your Location>**
  - **Member Item Fields > Type** ANY OF **Assembly/Bill Of Materials** and **Inventory Item**

[image: Criteria tab selections]

---

- **Criteria (Summary) Tab**

  1. Line 1

     - Type: Minimum
     - Field: Formula (Numeric)
     - Formula: `GREATEST(FLOOR(NVL({memberitem.locationquantityonhand},0)/{memberquantity}),0)`
     - Greater than 0
  2. Line 2

     - Type: Minimum
     - Field: Location Back Ordered
     - Greater than 0

[image: Criteria Tab (Summary)]

---

- **Results Tab**

  - **Internal ID** (Summary type **Group**)
  - **Name** (Summary type **Group**)
  - **Description** (Summary type **Group**)
  - **Inventory Location** (Summary type **Group**)
  - **Location Back Ordered** (Summary type **Group**)
  - **Formula (Numeric)** (Summary type **Minimum**): `GREATEST(FLOOR(NVL({memberitem.locationquantityonhand},0)/{memberquantity}),0)`
  - **Formula (Text)** (Summary type **Group**): `'<a href="/app/accounting/transactions/build.nl?location='||{inventorylocation.internalid}||'&item='||{internalid}||'">Build</a> | <a href="/app/common/item/item.nl?id='||{internalid}||'">Open</a>'`

[image: Results Tab Selections]

---

**Example of results:**
[image: Example of results]

---

**NOTES**

- **IMPORTANT**: You may want to change **locationquantityonhand** to **locationquantityavailable** in the formulas used in both the *Criteria (Summary)* and *Results* tabs.

  - Doing so will change the result to only show how many assemblies can be built without using items that are already committed to other customer orders.
- Clicking the "Build" link in the search results takes you straight to the Build Assembly page with the item and stock location pre-selected.

  - If you require work orders for your builds you can change the URL generated in the *Formula (Text)* field in the Results columns.
- Clicking the "Open" link in the search results takes you to the Item Record.

---

**BONUS**

If you'd like to be able to build the assembly without leaving the search results page you can add a column directly after the `Formula (Numeric)` column (the buildable quantity) as follows:

- **Formula (Text)** (Summary type **Group**): `'<a target="_blank" href="#" onclick=''try { itemid='||{internalid}||'; loc='||{inventorylocation.internalid}||'; qty=this.closest("td").previousElementSibling.textContent; qty=prompt("How many would you like to build?",qty); if(qty>0) { this.textContent = "PROCESSING"; rec=nlapiTransformRecord("assemblyitem",itemid,"assemblybuild",{"quantity":qty,"location":loc}); id=nlapiSubmitRecord(rec); this.textContent = "BUILT "+qty; this.removeAttribute("onclick"); this.href = "/app/accounting/transactions/build.nl?id="+id; } } catch(e) {     alert("ERROR: "+e.getCode()+": "+e.getDetails());     this.textContent = "ERROR"; } return false;''>Immediate</a>'`

This will create a link that says "Immediate" which, when clicked, will prompt the user to enter a quantity and will then create a build for that amount and record it in the search results so you can see which ones you've done (clicking the new "BUILT (qty)" text after a completed build will take you to the newly created Assembly Build record.)

Comment: Thanks Kane, I tried this and probably have made a mistake somewhere as there were no results. Be awesome if you can call me 04 10 50 60 10, would love to chat.

Comment: Kane, I checked through again and the only variance I can see is in the criteria for both location fields were I have "is any of BrandNet Dispatch Room, Military Shop Showroom, Production Room (medals), Warehouse. You have Inventory Location ANY OF - None - and <Your Location>. I added None and our locations and that did not help. 
 Cheers Stephen